# Laravel redirecting depending on user

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

Keep in mind that I am a newbie at Laravel. In my project, I have to create a website in which there are two users: teachers and students. In the registration form, a user has to select if he is a student or a teacher. After registration, I want that the website could redirect teacher to  teacher's view, student to student's view. Here are my code fragments in case it would be easier for you to help me:

My routes:

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home/{usertype}', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');


    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
        Route::resource('user', 'UserController', ['except' => ['show']]);
        Route::get('profile', ['as' => 'profile.edit', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@edit']);
        Route::put('profile', ['as' => 'profile.update', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@update']);
        Route::put('profile/password', ['as' => 'profile.password', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@password']);
    });
```

Radios to select user type:

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('usertype') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center" >
                            <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                                <input type="radio" id="customRadioInline1" name="usertype" value="mokytojas" class="custom-control-input" required autofocus>
                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadioInline1">Mokytojas</label>
                              </div>
                              <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                                <input type="radio" id="customRadioInline2" name="usertype" value ="paskaitu_lektorius" class="custom-control-input" >
                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadioInline2">Paskaitų lektorius</label>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post a concrete question: what are you trying, what is not working, what result do you need.

Answer (score 1):

In your registration controller or user controller, wherever makes sense, just redirect after creating the user.

```
if ($user->type == 'teacher') {
    return redirect()->route('teacher');
} else {
    return redirect()->route('student');
}
```

You'll need to name your routes to use the above. You can just redirect directly instead.